# Bundling with webpack from script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, jake

I am using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to bundle my Javascript files in my project:

```
webpack --config myconfig.webpack.config.
```

From commandline it is ok.

#### Building

However I would like to create a build task, I am using [jake](http://jakejs.com/), so in order to create the bundle I need to invoke `webpack` from Javascript.

I could not find the API online, I basically need something like this:

```
// Jakefile.js

var webpack = require("webpack");

desc('This is the default build task which also bundles stuff.');
task('default', function (params) {
    webpack.bundle("path-to-config"); // Something like this?
});
```

How do I achieve this?

#### Attempt 1

I have tried the following:

```
// Jakefile.js

var webpack = require("webpack");
var config = require("./webpack.config.js");

desc('This is the default build task which also bundles stuff.');
task('default', function (params) {
    webpack(config);
});
```

`webpack.config.js` is my config for webpack. When I use from commandline and reference that file the bundle is correctly created. But when using the above code it does not work. When I execute it, no errors, but the bundle is not emitted.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js

Comment: So just `webpack("--config", "path-to-config")`?

Comment: I think you don't need `bundle` I seem to be able to get mine working with `webpack(config)`...using webpack 3.

Comment: I'm using webpack 3.5.5 and `webpack(config)` does not do anything. Sorry had a typo, there is no `bundle` in my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Attempt 1**, you seem to be consuming the webpack's Node.js API by passing the config to webpack method. If you take this approach, webpack method will return a compiler object and you need to handle it correctly.
For e.g.,

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

var config = {}; // Your webpack config
var wpInstanceCompiler = webpack(config);
wpInstanceCompiler.run(function(err, stats) {
  if (stats.hasErrors()) {
    console.log(stats.toJson("verbose");
  }
});
```

This is how you execute a webpack config via the Node.js API. Unless you run the compiler instance, the output will not get generated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var lib = require(path.join(__dirname, "webpack.config.js"));

desc('Builds the projects and generates the library.');
task('default', function() {
    webpack(lib, function() { 
        console.log("Bundle successfully created!"); 
    });
});
```